# How to retrieve values from tera template by rocket framework?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket, tera

I need to get values from input form of tera template to rocket code. How can I do that?
Here is the template:

```html
{% extends "base" %}

{% block content %}
    <h3>Task:</h3>
    <ul>
        <p>{{task}}</p>
        <input type="text" name="answer">
    </ul>

    <p>Return to main menu <a href="/home">Home</a></p>
{% endblock content %}
```

I need somehow retrieve the value from  the field.
If there is a way to receive it by pressing "Enter" that would be even nicer.
Thank you for your attention.

I know what to do on the rocket end, but I don't know how to send data from tera templates.

Also, if somebody can say how to do it by pressing "Enter" for example, that would be really great.

Comment: You can just use an HTML form.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed It is just an example, templates are allowing more flexibility, and I want to know how to use it. Although I don't know how to do it with simple HTML, I need to know how to do it with tera templates.

Comment: Tera is just a tool that allows you to use variables and functions in HTML. In the end, it just outputs regular HTML. You should probably [learn how to use html forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) first. Then, you can capture the HTML data with [rocket form guards](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/requests/#forms).

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed Yeah, you are right, it is a simple html form, and I can treat it as an ordinary submitting form. Thank you for help.